# Why does the IO data need to be copy between user space and kernal space

Tags: io, kernel

All.
I'm learning the basic IO knowledge, but I'm puzzled about the IO data need to be copy between user space and kernal space, why?
Fox example, if I call the `read` method to read a file from my disk. The data is first stored in the kernal, and then notice the user process to copy the data to my user space. Why did't it directly read from disk to my user space?

Comment: What did you use to learn? Hardware usually works with hardware drivers  which program DMA actions. SATA/SAS/NVMe driver will post descriptor to hdd/ssd queue describing which block should be read and where to place it, by physical memory address. While hdd/ssd is searching for data and doing the DMA access, this (physical) memory should be kept in place, so it is allocated in kernel and controlled by it. When data is copied to physical memory, kernel (VFS) will copy it to the virt mem of userspace (with `read` syscall; or it may give it to user with `mmap` or `splice`). Don't trust user.

Comment: How to understand the sentence "Don't trust user"?

Comment: Driver can't ask device to do DMA directly from/to user controlled memory.  Malicious user (or incorrect program) may try to unmap this part of memory before DMA will be done; or he can change data before it will be read by device. Another problem in doing DMA is with older buses like PCI which are 32-bit and can't access all physical memory of the machine: they only can do DMA to like first GBs of phys memory (ISA - 16MB) and this part is managed by kernel in different way (DMA zone - `ZONE_DMA` - http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch11lev1sec2 "pages that are capable of undergoing DMA.")

Comment: Some links to "Linux Device Drivers" book - https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/, "Chapter 15: Memory Mapping and DMA" - https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf (with example of userspace driver "SCSI tape driver" in "Performing Direct I/O" page 435 or page 24 of pdf). There are also other variants of user-controlled I/O like https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/ELINUX/10693/1/Linux%20DMA%20from%20User%20Space-public.pdf or "zero-copy" https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/ http://www.mirlabs.org/ijcisim/regular_papers_2011/Paper2.pdf

Comment: Okay, I got you! Thank you!

Comment: @osgx *Driver can't ask device to do DMA directly from/to user controlled memory.* True in general.  However, to be (overly?) pedantic, direct IO can do DMA directly to/from memory mapped as user-addressable pages and eliminate the copy between kernel and user space.  Direct IO tends to be used by databases that do their own cache management (Think Oracle...).  It's also useful in streaming data where so much data is processed that there's no way data will ever be reread from the page cache.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, O_DIRECT (used by huge databases) is not direct IO of DMA to user-space buffer. It is just not for saving copy in the page cache and to disable temporal buffering.

Comment: @osgx `O_DIRECT` is merely the Linux implementation of direct IO.  [There are others](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=606585&seqNum=6):  "Direct I/O eliminates the second step by arranging for the DMA transfer to occur directly into the user's address space."

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Hmm, this O_DIRECT sometimes described as DMA to user buffer (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html - "File I/O is done directly to/from user-space buffers. .. NOTES The O_DIRECT flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os. "). But for doing DMA directly to user-space it is needed to give hardware access to physical page (it will be in DMA-accessible zone, or IOMMU is needed), so there is still work to lock user pages or even remapping them.

Comment: @osgx FWIW, direct IO is usually not worth the trouble. The only time I've found it useful is for a video processor I coded up for a customer.  It would just do a straight stream of many GB of video, extracting KLV metadata among other tasks.  It was so IO limited, using direct IO improved throughput by about 20-30%. This was on Solaris 10, using a QFS filesystem on a high-speed SAN. Solaris 10 has a really useful direct IO implementation - no alignment or IO size restrictions, likely for Oracle DBs.  Linux is a bit hit-or-miss, depending a lot on the filesystem, so it's a less useful there.

Comment: Also, there's the non-standard [`sendfile()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html):  "`sendfile()` copies data between one file descriptor and another.
       Because this copying is done within the kernel, `sendfile()` is more
       efficient than the combination of `read(2)` and `write(2)`. ..."